# Getting information from drop down list and submit button in while loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, submit

I'm using a while loop to list "gladiators" from my game and what kind of training they are set to. I want the user to be able to set the training, using a drop down menu. So the page would look something like:

Gladiator 1
Training: Not set.
Drop down menu | submit button

Gladiator 2
Training: Strength
Drop down menu | submit button

...and so on, for all the gladiators registered to the users ludus. The drop down menu consists of the different types of training you can chose for each gladiator.

The code I use goes like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
}
$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
$husinfotemp=mysql_query("SELECT * from `hus` WHERE `id`='$uid'") or die (mysql_error());
$husinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($husinfotemp) or die (mysql_error());
$nrofglads=$husinfo['nrofgladiators'];
$gladiatorsinfotemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gladiators`") or die (mysql_error());
$totalglads=mysql_num_rows($gladiatorsinfotemp);


$counter=1;
$countertotal=1;
while ($counter<=$nrofglads) {
    while ($countertotal<=$totalglads) {
        $gladiatorsinfotemp2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gladiators` WHERE `gladiatorid`='$countertotal'") or die (mysql_error());
        $gladiatorsinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($gladiatorsinfotemp2) or die (mysql_error());
        $ludusid=$gladiatorsinfo['ludusid'];
            if ($ludusid==$uid) {
                $name=$gladiatorsinfo['name'];
                $traininginfotemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `training` WHERE `gladiatorid`='$countertotal'") or die (mysql_error());
                $traininginfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($traininginfotemp);
                $trainingtype=$traininginfo['trainingtype'];
                $trainingtypetext=trainingtotext($trainingtype);
                ?><font size="3"><?php
                echo "<a href=gladiator.php?gladiatorid=$countertotal>$name</a>";?>
                </font><br /><?php
                echo "Training: ".$trainingtypetext.".";
                ?>
                <form action="">
                <select name="training">
                <option value="1">Strength</option>
                <option value="2">Agility</option>
                <option value="3">Quickness</option>
                <option value="4">Stamina</option>
                <option value="5">Attacks</option>
                <option value="6">Defence</option>
                <option value="7">Sword</option>
                <option value="8">Mace</option>
                <option value="9">Pole</option>
                <option value="10">Dagger</option>
                <option value="11">Unarmed</option>
                <option value="12">Net</option>
                <option value="13">Shield</option>
                <option value="14">Sparring</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" name="one"/>
                </form><?php
                if(isset ($_POST['one'])) {
                    if ($_POST['training']=='1') {
                        $trainingtype=1;
                        $updtraining=mysql_query("UPDATE `training` SET `trainingtype`='$trainingtype' WHERE `gladiatorid`='$countertotal'") or die (mysql_error());
                    }else echo "2";
                }

                $counter++;
                ?><br /><?php
            }
        $countertotal++;
    }


}



include ("footer.php");
?>
```

The problem is that when I click submit nothing is getting submitted. My question is if it is possible to use a while loop and this kind of drop down list + submit button system to set the training in the manner which I'm trying to use here?

To the experienced coders out there: I'm sorry you have to read such terrible code, I am a slacker trying to learn by reading simple uides whenever I stumble upon a problem. Not the best way to learn to create good code, I'm afraid ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the forms are concerned; you are adding the same button with the same name to all your forms, so you will not be able to distinguish which button was pressed.

A more logical solution would be to put your processing of the sent-in form at the top and add a hidden field to each form with the `gladiatorid` so that you know exactly which item the sent-in value applies to.

Apart from that you should switch to PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Could you please show me a small piece of code just showing how it would work with your more logical solution? I don't know how to add a hidden field like that.

I read that it's deprecated, but don't know what it means. According to wikipedia it usually means that something is superseded, which I understand as there is a better alternative, but not that the deprecated alternative has to be avoided.

My problem is that the tutorial that got me started was using mysql, and everything I do is now based on that little bit of coding I picked up from that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly if you intend to submit a form, you must provide it a right action source to submit the form to, secondly you if you intend to use a POST method, this should be addressed in the form's properties as well:

```
<form action='myfile.php' method='post'>
```

and one more important thing, you are using a depreciated functions for connecting and querying Mysql, you should use Mysqli or PDO extentions and use binding to prevent future SQL injections.

Comment: Ok.

I don't really get the form action stuff. I do not want to send the information to another page, but use it to update my sql table. Am I using a bad approach for what I try to achieve?

If I can somehow send two pieces of information to another page, training type and gladiator id, then I could always set the target page to use that information to update the table, but that seems like a bad/slow sollution.

I've read before that mysql is deprecated, but does that mean that it needs to be avoided, or just that there are better alternatives?

Comment: the action attribute must be set to a file (in your case it is a php file) that will handle the form data, it sure can be the very same file that contains the form itself. Mysql is not depreciated, but the API you are using to contact mysql is, We recommended you to use PDO or Mysqli, personaly I prefer [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. You helped me into finding a solution. I removed the if (isset ... part, and worked a bit using your tips and google->a guide. Now the form part looks like this:

```
<form action="settraining.php" method="post">
            <select name="training">
            <option value="1">Strength</option>
            <option value="2">Agility</option>
            <option value="3">Quickness</option>
            <option value="4">Stamina</option>
            <option value="5">Attacks</option>
            <option value="6">Defence</option>
            <option value="7">Sword</option>
            <option value="8">Mace</option>
            <option value="9">Pole</option>
            <option value="10">Dagger</option>
            <option value="11">Unarmed</option>
            <option value="12">Net</option>
            <option value="13">Shield</option>
            <option value="14">Sparring</option>
            <input type="hidden" name="gladiatorid" value="<?php echo "$countertotal" ?>">
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" name="one"/>
            </form>
```

And on settraining I get the information using:

```
$trainingtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['training']);
$gladiatorid=htmlspecialchars($_POST['gladiatorid']);
```

And it seems like everything works fine :)